# Accessing the label text through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Looking access the label text.

I can find the value of the input tag via:

```html
<label for="t">Try this <input type="text" id="t" /></label>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('t').value)" value="Click me!"/>
```

But what is the method to access the label's text "Try this" ?

using .innerHTML yields nothing.  .parentNode.value yielded undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<label for="t">Try this <input type="text" id="t" /></label>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('t').parentNode.innerText)" value="Click me!"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. .parentNode.innerText  -- didn't want to have to have to add an id to the label in addition to a for property.  Seemed redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the element by their tag name using `document.getElementsTagName()` method. This method returns all elements with the tag `<label></label>`

```html
<label for="t">Try this <input type="text" id="t" /></label>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerText)" value="Click me!"/>
```

Comment: why [0]? [1]? [2]?

Comment: because `document.getElementsTagName()` retrieves all existing element with the given tag name, therefore, it obviously returns array even if there is only one element

Comment: I know this but why [0]?

Comment: You really don't  know? we need index to retrieve element from array.don't we?

Comment: Where are you going with this?

Comment: This label may be in any index of array that returned by document.getElementsByTagName. We dont have all code for find index of it.

Comment: There is only one element with tag `label`, so the array has only one element. I don't know about you but I cannot use index [1],[2] to retrieve the first element from array.

Comment: [0]..[n] would spagetti code it. And if I have other labels on the page or div, it might muck up everything.  Want to stick with getElementById(). The "for" property is not working well with the input tag's id reference. Not sure why. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What if I have lots of label and inputs and only one button. which one to select then?. OP already know to get element by Id, but he did not put the `id` of the label, he could've done that. That's why I wrote the code according to the question. If we've to guess we can guess a lot. we can produce a lot of scenario

Comment: Yes Ali I see that you did mention why See the answer from C.D.

Comment: Small exercise but interesting anyway. Enjoy more knowledge today!

Answer (score 0):

Give your label an id, let's say lbl:

```
<label id="lbl" for="t">Try this <input type="text" id="t" /></label>
```

Now in javascript, you can access the text using:

```
document.getElementById('lbl').innerText
```

you can also trim the result to get rid of spaces.

Comment: That does not work.  It returns Try this <input type="text" id="t">.

Comment: .innerHTML returns Try this <input type="text" id="t">.

Comment: as you can see in the answer, use innerText not innerHTML

Comment: .innerText will return "Try this" which is what I am looking for but each label has to also have a id to match the input tag id.  the for property doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: This is depending on your HTML structure which is not mentioned in your question.

furthermore, if your inputs are always nested within the label, you can use the inputelement.parentNode()  .

On the other hand, the for property tells the label which input to focus when clicked

Comment: The HTML structure is what I posted. using .innerText yields the entire node contents. Not the "Try this" text.  I want the inner text not the inner HTML.

Comment: no. the innerText will not return any HTML content. please double check your code or place it here.

and as i understand, you do not want to assign id's for the labels?

Comment: My code is placed and C.D. answered. Please double check. Your answer adds more work.